# Metadata on APK files?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, compression, metadata

Is there any **metadata** on  **APK** files ?
I know that in images and several other files it exists, but I'm wondering about APK.
If it exists, **how can I read it** ?
I build my apps on **eclipse**, does it store any **information about the system** on the exported APK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try out `aapt dump badging` and also check out the `androidManifest.xml` file you can obtain from the apk by decoding it, for example, with [apktool](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/).

Example of running `aapt dump badging` on `je.fit.apk`:

```
PS C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\17.0.0> aapt dump badging je.fit.apk
package: name='je.fit' versionCode='60' versionName='3.5.0109'
uses-permission:'android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.VIBRATE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.INTERNET'
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE'
uses-configuration:
uses-gl-es:'0xffffffff'
sdkVersion:'7'
targetSdkVersion:'7'
application-label:'JEFIT'
application-icon-120:'res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png'
application-icon-160:'res/drawable/icon.png'
application-icon-240:'res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png'
application-icon-320:'res/drawable-xhdpi/icon.png'
application: label='JEFIT' icon='res/drawable/icon.png'
launchable-activity: name='je.fit.Jefit'  label='JEFIT' icon=''
uses-permission:'android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-implied-permission:'android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE','requested WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.wifi'
uses-implied-feature:'android.hardware.wifi','requested android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE, or android.permission.CHANGE
_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE permission'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.touchscreen'
uses-implied-feature:'android.hardware.touchscreen','assumed you require a touch screen unless explicitly made optional'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.screen.portrait'
uses-implied-feature:'android.hardware.screen.portrait','one or more activities have specified a portrait orientation'
main
other-activities
supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large'
supports-any-density: 'true'
locales: '--_--'
densities: '120' '160' '240' '320'
```